# Use while()+sleep() instead of semaphore or mutex?

Tags: java, android, c, multithreading, macos

I'm working with threads, and sometimes need to halt one thread while waiting for the other to complete. I'll sometimes use a semaphore to keep a function in another thread from returning before it finishes (like waiting for the device's camera to shut down). The problem is, sometimes a function is called on a main thread and it locks up the app until it returns. In this case, I could use a while loop that calls sleep() to keep the "spinning beach ball" from showing to the user. Is there a better solution to this that would prevent the beach ball?

Comment: you can look into **spinlocks**.. It might be helpful to you

Comment: The problem with sleeping is that you almost invariably sleep for longer than necessary, or else your sleep is so short that you are really just spin-waiting, which is wasteful of CPU.

Comment: What do you mean by 'locks up the app'?   GUI does not respond to messages?

Comment: Martin, yes, since the main thread is blocked, there's no response to user input. On a Mac, this displays the beach ball cursor, and on Android you get a Logcat warning that the main thread is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if posix threads can be used on Android, if so take a look to [pthread_cond_timedwait](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_timedwait):

```
static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER; 

void *timer_handler(void *handler)
{
    struct timespec end;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);

    end.tv_sec += 5;

    int stop = 1;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex)

    int error = pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &mutex, &end); // Wait 5 seconds

    if (error == ETIMEDOUT)
    {
        stop = 0;
    }
    else if (error != 0)
    {
        perror("pthread_cond_timedwait");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex)

    if (stop == 0)
    {
        // Do your stuff here
    }
}
```